# How to parse <a name and <image src= inside <li tag using php?

Tags: php, regex, dom, simplexml, preg-match-all

I got a html string with lots of `<li> .. </li>` sets. I want to parse following data from each set of `<li> ...</li>` :

```
   1: call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456
   2: mango season
   3: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png
```

I used preg_match_all to get the first value but how to get the second and third value ?
I would be happy if some show me get second and third item .Thanks in advance.

php:

```
preg_match_all('/getit(.*?)detailFruit/', $code2, $match);

var_dump($match);

  // iterate the new array
  for($i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i++)
{
$code3=str_replace('getit(\'', '', $match[0]);
$code4=str_replace('&amp;\',detailFruit', '', $code3);
echo "<br>".$code4[$i];
}
```

sample `<li> ..</li>` data:

```
<li><a id="FR123456" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123456');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456&amp;',detailFruit,false);">mango season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png">
            </li>
```

**Edit:** I used DOM now I got 2 and 3 value how to get first value using DOM ?

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code2);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Empty array to hold all links to return
$result = array();

//Loop through each <li> tag in the dom
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
    //Loop through each <a> tag within the li, then extract the node value
    foreach($li->getElementsByTagName('a') as $links){
        $result[] = $links->nodeValue;
        echo $result[0] . "\n";
    }

    $imgs = $xpath->query("//li/img/@src");

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo $img->nodeValue . "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing, use a parser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?rq=1.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Per your suggestion i used DOM but how to get the first value too using DOM so i get all three values for each set using DOM ?

Comment: What is the `first value` in your example?

Comment: I mean this value inside onclick :call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456

Comment: You can get the attribute with `echo $links->getAttribute('onclick');`, From there you could use a regex, I don't know of a way to parse JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question :-) The following solution uses a combination of `DOMDocument/SimpleXML` to get the values 2 & 3 easily. `DomDocument` was used as your HTML snippet was corrupted. To actually get your link (value 1) from the JavaScript content, a simple regex was used:

```
~getit\('([^']+)'\)~
# search for getit( and a singlequote literally
# capture everything up to (but not including) a new single quote
# this is saved in the group 1
```

**A complete walkthrough** can be found below (obviously I made up the `banana` part):

```
<?php
$html = '<ul>
<li><a id="FR123456" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID(\'123456\');getit(\'call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456&amp;\',detailFruit,false);">mango season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png"></li>
<li><a id="FR7890" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID(\'7890\');getit(\'call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=7890&amp;\',detailFruit,false);">bananas</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_7890.png"></li>
        </ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

# xpath to find list items
$items = $xml->xpath("//ul/li");

$regex = "~getit\('([^']+)'\)~";

# loop over the items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $title = $item->a->__toString();
    $imgLink = $item->img["src"];

    $jsLink = $item->a["onclick"];

    preg_match_all($regex, $jsLink, $matches);
    $jsLink = $matches[1][0];

    echo "Title: $title, imgLink: $imgLink, jsLink: $jsLink\n";
    // output: Title: mango season, imgLink: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png, jsLink: call.php?category=fruits&fruitid=123456&
    //         Title: bananas, imgLink: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_7890.png, jsLink: call.php?category=fruits&fruitid=7890&
}

?>
```